# 'git tag --contains <commit>' without cloning the repo?

Tags: git, github

Sometimes i want to check what tags contain a specific commit (for example - a bug fix which I need and want to know what package versions are good for me).

The only way I know, is: `git tag --contains <commit_id>`, but that requires cloning the project.

Can I do it without cloning? Either from the command line or directly via the GitHub website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHub does display branches and tags containing a commit in the web interface. Look at the commit description box. Eg. for https://github.com/StackExchange/blackbox/commit/3e9091722cdbc000831d22274cc5b92f9a819dae we see master, v1.20170611, v1.20170309, stable and production.

So does Gitlab: eg. https://gitlab.com/mailman/mailman/commit/3df8d5182b44148bbd4b43f5474cd67b2ca699f9 is in master, cherry-pick-f2f7cfc5, click-cli, release-3.1, testing-gitlab and 3.1.0.

Bitbucket doesn't seem to do it and neither does gitweb.

Comment: Thanks for the example! In my case the commit wasn't in any release (apparently...) so I didn't have the tags listed.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to try you need that repository. then only git will find your given commit id on specific repository otherwise it will say **bad object**

for eg:

if you are in some repository 
  you're trying `git tag --contains <commit_id>` with commit which is belongs to another repository means it will say bad object...

**BTW** you need repository to try this...

you can view it in [github](https://github.com) under your `repository -> code section` 
and then select **commits** will list your commits with tag

Answer (score 0):

To manipulate a git repository using advanced commands like this one, git needs to have a **full copy** of it.

There's no clean way around it, except if github as implemented it (not the case for this one).